# Jetpack Compose Desktop switch to new window

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop

Hey I'm pretty new to Kotlin and am trying my hand at a GUI as my first small project.
For this I am using Jetpack Compose Desktop. I have already written a first small login window ( not the one in the GIF), and would like to open a new window with the "actual" content after logging in (not an external one, but in the same window). 
Here is a video that may help you to understand what I mean:
[image]

(Not mine but thanks to Agon Mustafa - [uplabs](https://www.uplabs.com/posts/simple-login-animation))

So that one continues with the registration in the same window and does not have to open a separate window for it. Hope you can help me:)

Comment: Modify some state that triggers recomposition, where you render the revised content based upon that state (e.g., one branch of a `when()` does the one screen and another branch does another screen). Note that Jetpack Compose is still in alpha and Compose for Desktop is even younger. I would argue that neither are a great choice for somebody new to Kotlin.

Comment: You might need an state management library. You can check these 3:
https://github.com/arkivanov/Decompose or
https://github.com/adrielcafe/voyager.
Each has its own way to handle state. I created my own library for this matter, you can check how I do it here: https://github.com/pablichjenkov/uistate3

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to open and close multiple windows:

```
fun main() = application {
    val applicationState = remember { MyApplicationState() }

    for (window in applicationState.windows) {
        key(window) {
            MyWindow(window)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun ApplicationScope.MyWindow(
    state: MyWindowState
) = Window(onCloseRequest = state::close, title = state.title) {
    MenuBar {
        Menu("File") {
            Item("New window", onClick = state.openNewWindow)
            Item("Exit", onClick = state.exit)
        }
    }
}

private class MyApplicationState {
    val windows = mutableStateListOf<MyWindowState>()

    init {
        windows += MyWindowState("Initial window")
    }

    fun openNewWindow() {
        windows += MyWindowState("Window ${windows.size}")
    }

    fun exit() {
        windows.clear()
    }

    private fun MyWindowState(
        title: String
    ) = MyWindowState(
        title,
        openNewWindow = ::openNewWindow,
        exit = ::exit,
        windows::remove
    )
}

private class MyWindowState(
    val title: String,
    val openNewWindow: () -> Unit,
    val exit: () -> Unit,
    private val close: (MyWindowState) -> Unit
) {
    fun close() = close(this)
}
```

You can read more in the
[tutorials](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/tree/master/tutorials/Window_API_new#open-and-close-multiple-windows)
of Compose for desktop

Comment: I tried to post the answer 6 months ago but it was deleted since I didn't provide the code so I have to answer it again) but this might be helpful